# How do I get my files back on my USB?

Tags: usb, data-recovery

[image: Screenshot of my USB]

I have a problem with my USB. I used it on Wednesday last week and it was working just fine. I haven't used it since and it hasn't been damaged.
Now when I put my USB on my laptop, all my files were replaced by the files shown in the picture. Does anyone know how I can get my files back?

Comment: You may try some data recovery tools, but as apparently you aren't an expert, maybe the best is to hire a professional for that (if your data is of a high value).

Comment: Is it a thumb drive or an external drive? Did you use it on the same computer/same operating system last time? Did you use the safely eject feature?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news, but you won't be able to **easily** "get your files back"; you need to start looking for any backups that might have been left behind.

Look at the dates of those files. Most of those are clearly garbage, far in the past or in the future, meaning that something got written where the file listing should have been, and the file listing has been overwritten, and lost. But several files all bear the same timestamp, that of February 17th, 2018, at 20:58. **This cannot be a chance**. And it means that something, at that time, wrote to the file listing area *as if it was a listing area*, i.e., at that point the data had already become garbage.

This is a common consequence of incorrect device removal; which might have happened by accident, or because the device connector wasn't establishing a solid electrical connection. You might even be able to find traces of what happened in the Windows event log by running the `eventvwr` utility.

So it's not a matter of getting the correct and intact data, currently *interpreted* as garbage, to be interpreted correctly. That data has been replaced by garbage.

Did you lose *everything*? Probably not. What must be done now is read the USB data as raw information, and sift that information for its content. This can be done with several file formats that have strong internal consistency and clearly recognizable internal data markers (JPEG files, PDF files, most Office documents, etc.). There are data recovery programs that will do this (Recuva, Easeus, etc.).

The difficulty lies in how data is organized on a device: your documents are not stored contiguously but broken ("fragmented") into small chunks, the chunks fitted between other files' chunks in order to maximize space utilization, and then there's a master file table area where the system writes which chunk belongs to which file. If that area got damaged, you'll only be able to recover those files that were not fragmented.

However, whatever you do, have a professional do this for you. Meddling further with a damaged device can easily lessen, or destroy any chance of recovering any file at all.